# How to setup appointment in outlook with timezone

Tags: vba, outlook

I have written a code which creates the appointment in outlook 2016, but I am stuck here to change the time zone. Can anybody help here thanks in advance.

```
Sub Outlook_Appointment()
Dim o As Outlook.Application
Set o = New Outlook.Application

Dim ONS As Outlook.Namespace
Set ONS = o.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim CAL_FOL As Outlook.Folder
Set CAL_FOL = ONS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

Dim myapt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Set myapt = CAL_FOL.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

With myapt

    .Display
    .Start = Date + TimeValue("15:30:00")
    .End = Date + TimeValue("16:30:00")
    .Location = "Seattle"
    .Subject = "Discussion"
    .Body = "This is a test mail to block the calendar"
    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = TimeValue("00:15:00")
    .To = "abc@gmail.com"
    .Save

End With
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to use [AppointmentItem.StartTimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.starttimezone) and AppointmentItem.EndTimeZone

Comment: Hi I have tried as mentioned by you. But I am not sure how to send the value? Could you please give me an example? In my code: ``` With myapt .Display .StartTimeZone = What should I pass here for UK .EndTimeZone = What should I pass here for UK End With ```

Answer (score 0):

The [AppointmentItem.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.start) property value is always represented in the local time zone, check out [Application.TimeZones.CurrentTimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.timezones.currenttimezone) which returns a [TimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.timezone) value that represents the current Windows system local time zone.

The time zone information is used to map the appointment to the correct UTC time when the appointment is saved, and into the correct local time when the item is displayed in the calendar.

The [AppointmentItem.StartTimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.starttimezone) property returns or sets a `TimeZone` value that corresponds to the time zone for the start time of the appointment.

The [AppointmentItem.EndInEndTimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.endinendtimezone) property returns or sets a Date value that represents the end date and time of the appointment expressed in the `AppointmentItem.EndTimeZone`.

Comment: Hi @Eugene Astafiev,

I have tried as mentioned by you. But I am not sure how to send the value? Could you please give me an example?

In my code:

```
With myapt
    .Display
    .StartTimeZone = What should I pass here for UK
    .EndTimeZone = What should I pass here for UK
End With
```